# Memory useage 100% when use brush draw obj

Tags: objects

I'm drawing directly from 3D view mode, memory up to 100% and it can't go down, is it a bug? It doesn't happen in uv/image editor mode.

environment:
amd ryzen7
memory 16G
blender version 2.79
obj faces: 2584 polygons

Edit:
That is the obj link: https://free3d.com/3d-model/heart-v1--404644.html
"Draw" means using a brush to hold down the left mouse button while sweeping over an obj in TexturePaint Mode.

[image]

Comment: That's a helluva lot of information you give us there to work with. Care to elaborate what you mean by "draw"? Does "obj" stand for object or the file format? How many vertices are we talking about?  Maybe add some images? [This](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) might be useful for you.

Comment: That is the obj link: https://free3d.com/3d-model/heart-v1--404644.html

Comment: I have reedited the main thread content, please read it